# Cell probe model vs transdichotomous ram

Tags: computability, time-complexity, machine-models

can someone explain me the difference between those two (cell probe model and transdichotomous ram)?

In cpm I'm allowed to do computation for free, and complexity of algorithm is just a number of memory reads/writes. Can I use words as pointers in that model? Is the memory size fixed or unbounded?

In transdichotomous ram memory is a table of words indexed from 0 to S - 1 for given S. words have fixed size and serve as pointers. I can read/write constant number of cells at constant time. What about complexity of operations? Are computation free?

I don't feel the difference between them.

Thanks for help!

Comment: The main practical difference is that the simpler cell probe model is used for lower bounds, while the more complex transdichotomous RAM model is used for upper bounds.